# Could Jesus understand (and read) Latin?

Tags: historical-jesus, latin

I read that Jesus probably spoke Arameic and Hebrew. And that a Bible verse indicated that he could read.

Jesus lived in the Roman empire, so Latin was known by at least some people in the region.

Is there any indication in scripture that Jesus could understand a little Latin?
If not, is it reasonable to believe that a typical man born in the same region in the same year was able to understand/read at least some basic Latin words?

Comment: The answers to the linked question don't talk about Latin much, but they do say that the Roman Empire used Greek predominantly in Judea.

Comment: The linked question is IMHO about his main language, not about being able to understand a few words... Good point about Greek though.

Comment: He spoke with Pontius Pilate. I wonder what languages Pontius Pilate knew.